# Vuejs DOM doesn't update after fetching data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have bound an array `events` to a component tag `<scheduler>` containing events to fill in a scheduler app (dhtmlx scheduler). However, **the DOM doesn't seeem to refresh itself** when data is retrieved by the `getEvents` methods triggered when vue instance is created.

There is 2 vue files I work with: App.vue containing the main app component and the Scheduler.vue file containing the scheduler component.

The thing is that when I modify something in the Scheduler.vue file and save it, it correctly take the updated `events` array into account.
Scheduler parse the data in the `events` prop when DOM is mounted in scheduler component.

Therefore is there something I can do to get the updated array ?

Here is the **App.vue**:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="container">
      <scheduler v-bind:events="events"></scheduler>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Scheduler from './components/Scheduler.vue';
import auth from './components/auth/index'
import data from './components/data/index'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Scheduler
  },
  data() {
    return {
      events: []
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getEvents();
  },
  watch: {
    events: function(value) {
      console.log('updated');
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async getEvents() {
      try {
        const token = await auth.getToken(this);
        const thattoken = await auth.getThatToken(this, token);
        await data.getOgustData(this, token, '/calendar/events', 307310564, this.events);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Here is **Scheduler.vue**:

```
<template lang="html">
  <div ref="scheduler_here" class="dhx_cal_container" style='width:100%; height:700px;'>
    <div class="dhx_cal_navline">
      <div class="dhx_cal_prev_button">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="dhx_cal_next_button">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="dhx_cal_today_button"></div>
      <div class="dhx_cal_date"></div>
      <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="day_tab" style="right:204px;"></div>
      <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="week_tab" style="right:140px;"></div>
      <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="month_tab" style="right:76px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dhx_cal_header"></div>
    <div class="dhx_cal_data"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import 'dhtmlx-scheduler'
import 'dhtmlx-scheduler/codebase/locale/locale_fr';
import 'dhtmlx-scheduler/codebase/ext/dhtmlxscheduler_readonly.js';

export default {
  name: 'scheduler',
  props: {
    events: {
      type: Array,
      default () {
        return [{
          id: '',
          text: '',
          start_date: '',
          end_date: '',
        }]
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    scheduler.config.xml_date = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i';
    // disable left buttons on lightbox
    scheduler.config.buttons_left = [];
    // enable cancel button on lightbox's right wing
    scheduler.config.buttons_right = ['dhx_cancel_btn'];
    // changing cancel button label
    scheduler.locale.labels['icon_cancel'] = 'Fermer';
    // hide lightbox in month view
    scheduler.config.readonly_form = true;
    // hide select bar in day and week views
    scheduler.config.select = false;
    scheduler.config.lightbox.sections = [
      {
        name: "description",
        height: 20,
        map_to: "text",
        type: "textarea",
        focus: true
      }
    ];

    scheduler.init(this.$refs.scheduler_here, new Date(), 'month');
    scheduler.parse(this.$props.events, 'json');
  },
}
</script>

<style lang="css" scoped>
  @import "~dhtmlx-scheduler/codebase/dhtmlxscheduler.css";
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

`getOgustData` can't populate `events` in a way that Vue can observe. Since you're passing it as an argument, the array itself can be updated, but it's not a reactive array. Try

```
var newEvents;
await data.getOgustData(this, token, '/calendar/events', 307310564, newEvents);
this.events = newEvents;
```

Assigning to `this.events` is something Vue can notice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I created the `eventsArr` prop because I couldn't figure out why the prop wasn't updated in DOM.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I created the `eventsArr` prop because I couldn't figure out why the `events` prop wasn't updated in DOM. So I made `events` point to `eventsArr` to see if update was taken into account. Sorry for the misunderstanding(I have edited the code of App.vue to let only the `events` prop use). Even though, the `events` array is only taken into account when I modify something in my scheduler component.

Comment: I saw that you had taken `eventsArr` back out of your question, and I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks again. So I have followed your answer and edited my code as following: `this.events = await data.getOgustData(this, ogustToken, '/calendar/events', 307310564);` in `getEvents` method. You will notice that the `getOgustData` is now returning an array of events. However, DOM is still unable to retrieve the `events` array updated. Unless, I do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved. The issue didn't come from Vue but rather from the dhtmlx scheduler which wasn't parsing events when `events` was updated.

I ended up watching for any changes to `events` and thus, parsing it when it updates.

Thanks again for the help provided.

App.vue :

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="container">
      <scheduler v-bind:events="events"></scheduler>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Scheduler from './components/Scheduler.vue';
import auth from './components/auth/index'
import data from './components/data/index'
import 'dhtmlx-scheduler'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Scheduler
  },
  data() {
    return {
      events: []
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getEvents();
  },
  watch: {
    events: function(value) {
      scheduler.parse(this.events, 'json');
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async getEvents() {
      const token = await auth.getToken(this);
      const apiToken = await auth.getApiToken(this, token);
      this.events = await data.getApiData(this, apiToken, '/calendar/events', 307310564, this.events);
    }
  },
}
</script>
```