# How to display response from api whereof data is changing continuously?

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, websocket, socket.io

I am using vuejs and Axios.

I have an API, whose response is changing continuously and I want to display that updated data on the front end without reloading the page.

I am using this API https://canvasjs.com/services/data/datapoints.php?xstart=1&ystart=10&length=10&type=json

Currently, I am doing something this

```
methods: {
    getLiveData(){
        axios.get("https://canvasjs.com/services/data/datapoints.php?xstart=1&ystart=10&length=10&type=json")
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
                this.liveData = response.data;
            })          
        }       
    }
```

I am calling this function through mounted, here i am getting the response but its not changing it self I have to hard reload the page.How I will get the data updated automatically.

So far I have found about few plugins, but stuck at how to use that like https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-socket.io and a term websocket but dont know how to use this also.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you call `getLiveData()` on `mounted`. If that is the only time you call the method, it's the only time that the data will be updated. Try calling the method with `setInterval`:

```
mounted() {
  setInterval(this.getLiveData, 150);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have achieved this with setInterval, but I want to use websocket.If I am wrong please tell me

Answer (score 0):

Put `this.liveData` in watcher. 
Check this example: 
[Vuejs DOM doesn't update after fetching data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45979820/vuejs-dom-doesnt-update-after-fetching-data)

Comment: Thanks for the reply bro,Watch property may be a solution but I want to achieve this with websocket. If I am wrong please tell me